# Program crashes when trying to call a function in C++ DLL from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllexport

I have a C++ dll that contains different trigonometry functions and some exported functions returning dll information and result:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

double(*mid)(double);

double csin(double x) {
    return std::sin(x);
}

double ccos(double x) {
    return std::cos(x);
}

double ctan(double x) {
    return std::tan(x);
}

double ccot(double x) {
    return 1 / std::tan(x);
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall get_name() {
    char * name = "Trigonometry";
    return name;
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall get_info() {
    char * name = "sin|cos|tan|cot";
    return name;
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall set_func(char *name) {
    if (name == "sin") mid = &csin;
    if (name == "cos") mid = &ccos;
    if (name == "tan") mid = &ctan; 
    if (name == "cot") mid = &ccot;
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall calc(double x){
    return mid(x);
};
```

In C# program I try to call `GetName()` function to get the name of my dll but the program crashes with the message that the program exited with the code -1073740940 (0xc0000374).

Here is a part of code where program crashes (it happens when the last line is executed):

```
IntPtr plugin = LoadLibrary(filename);
if (plugin == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to load plugin!");
    return;
}

IntPtr func_gn = GetProcAddress(plugin, "_get_name@0");
IntPtr func_gi = GetProcAddress(plugin, "_get_info@0");
IntPtr func_se = GetProcAddress(plugin, "_set_func@4");
IntPtr func_ca = GetProcAddress(plugin, "_calc@8");
if (func_gn == IntPtr.Zero || func_ca == IntPtr.Zero || func_gi == IntPtr.Zero || func_se == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Missing some functions!");
    return;
}

Base b = new Base(plugin,
      (Base.InfoDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(func_gn, typeof(Base.InfoDelegate)),
      (Base.InfoDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(func_gi, typeof(Base.InfoDelegate)),
      (Base.SetDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(func_se, typeof(Base.SetDelegate)),
      (Base.CalcDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(func_ca, typeof(Base.CalcDelegate)));

Console.WriteLine("Plugin {0} loaded", b.GetName()); // <- crash here
```

`Base` class:

```
class Base
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate string InfoDelegate();
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void SetDelegate(string fname);
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate double CalcDelegate(double x);

    public IntPtr dll;
    public InfoDelegate GetName;
    public InfoDelegate GetInfo;
    public SetDelegate SetFunc;
    public CalcDelegate Calc;

    public Base(IntPtr dll, InfoDelegate name, InfoDelegate info, SetDelegate set, CalcDelegate calc)
    {
        this.dll = dll;
        this.GetInfo = info;
        this.GetName = name;
        this.SetFunc = set;
        this.Calc = calc;
    }
}
```

There is nothing in the console when the mentioned line is executed. It just closes without any error windows.

What is the error and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Thanks to `Hans Passant` for his helpful answer. But there is another function that, as it turned out, does not work. I try to print the results of sin function for arguments in range between `start` and `end` with the `step` step.

Here is the part of C# code where error happens:

```
plugin.SetFunc("sin");
Console.WriteLine("Result:");
for (double i = start; i <= end; i += step)
{
    Console.WriteLine(plugin.Calc(i)); // <- crash here
}
```

It throws `System.AccessViolationException`. It says that there is attempt to  access protected memory. I think it is because of that mid pointer in the 5th line of dll code. Is there a way to get over the problem?

Comment: Functions that return char* are difficult.  Normally a big memory management problem since the storage for the string needs to be released.  Which is what the pinvoke marshaller tries to do, kaboom with 0xc0000374 since it is not stored on the heap.  In this specific case the storage should not be released at all since you use literals.   In other words, you actually return a const char*.  Change the return type to IntPtr, recover the string with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but I don't think you should compare `char *` using `name == "sin"`.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you, it helped. But now I can't call Calc function as it attempts to access protected memory.

Comment: Dirk told you about that one, you must use strcmp() to compare strings.  Pretty crucial to be able to debug this so you can see this going wrong.  Project > Properties > Debug, tick "Enable native code debugging".  Set breakpoints on set_func and calc.

Comment: `name == "sin"` you just cant do this. try to use `std::map` for that